# Bootstrap scrollspry doesn't highlight my nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know what's going on here but my Bootstrap scrollspry code doesn't work. It's not highlighting any of the nav. Here's what I have got so far:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#myScrollspy">

<div id="container" class="container">

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-9">

<a name="routing"></a><h2 class="text-info" style="margin-top:20px;">Pre Audit, Routing &amp; Access Info</h2>
<p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mattis purus nec lorem dignissim consectetur. Phasellus nibh massa, molestie et malesuada ac, eleifend eu nunc. Curabitur eget enim quis lorem venenatis semper. Aliquam nec laoreet arcu, luctus egestas velit. Nunc convallis nisl id velit euismod, ut iaculis est facilisis. Fusce luctus neque justo, ut consequat justo porta non. Duis mollis malesuada eros in lacinia. Integer ac tristique nisi. Donec bibendum rutrum odio.</p>

<p>Quisque mattis dui metus, in congue ante dictum ut. Sed posuere laoreet pulvinar. Nunc bibendum sapien eget leo luctus, ut bibendum velit sodales. Nam in bibendum erat. Sed a mattis quam, eget dignissim urna. Aliquam tristique purus adipiscing aliquet bibendum. Etiam sed pretium tellus. Curabitur euismod dolor id suscipit vehicula. Sed tincidunt arcu sed velit convallis, id volutpat metus scelerisque. Phasellus tempus et elit eu dictum. Suspendisse tempus justo neque, id semper dui molestie nec. Aliquam luctus dui ac commodo laoreet.</p>

<p>Donec non ligula et urna dapibus euismod et nec tortor. Nullam mauris dui, dignissim vel varius et, eleifend at felis. Curabitur adipiscing nisi sed elit interdum ultricies. In sit amet turpis quis nisl porttitor facilisis vel quis justo. Curabitur fringilla viverra sodales. Nulla eget molestie quam. Etiam sed mi tellus. Ut fermentum diam sem, vel dictum mauris elementum aliquet. Vestibulum sed nibh felis. Nullam ac consectetur lectus, feugiat congue velit. Phasellus ullamcorper, erat eget volutpat semper, erat risus rutrum urna, sit amet lacinia augue tortor sit amet libero. Nam rutrum pulvinar nisl elementum aliquet. Duis ac blandit arcu.</p>

<p>Aenean nec massa est. Vivamus lobortis rutrum augue, eget luctus felis mattis non. Nulla lacinia, turpis non aliquet pretium, leo neque vulputate turpis, sit amet lobortis magna leo quis libero. Praesent id leo consequat, blandit ipsum in, scelerisque libero. Integer sagittis tempus neque, vel faucibus risus porttitor eu. Morbi euismod, enim non aliquam blandit, ligula tellus pellentesque dui, a posuere neque tellus non mi. Donec commodo sit amet lorem nec tristique. Donec eget neque massa. Morbi adipiscing mauris nec orci pharetra, tincidunt placerat nulla cursus. Quisque pulvinar lacinia nunc nec faucibus. Aliquam lorem arcu, scelerisque a turpis nec, tincidunt feugiat lacus. Nam elementum vitae diam luctus elementum. Mauris a ligula vel tortor lacinia posuere. Sed vestibulum at nisl eget mattis. Maecenas eget dignissim mauris, id aliquet quam. Nullam viverra lorem eu mollis rutrum.</p>

<a name="contract"></a><h2 class="text-info" style="margin-top:20px;">Contract Details</h2>

<p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mattis purus nec lorem dignissim consectetur. Phasellus nibh massa, molestie et malesuada ac, eleifend eu nunc. Curabitur eget enim quis lorem venenatis semper. Aliquam nec laoreet arcu, luctus egestas velit. Nunc convallis nisl id velit euismod, ut iaculis est facilisis. Fusce luctus neque justo, ut consequat justo porta non. Duis mollis malesuada eros in lacinia. Integer ac tristique nisi. Donec bibendum rutrum odio.</p>

<p>Quisque mattis dui metus, in congue ante dictum ut. Sed posuere laoreet pulvinar. Nunc bibendum sapien eget leo luctus, ut bibendum velit sodales. Nam in bibendum erat. Sed a mattis quam, eget dignissim urna. Aliquam tristique purus adipiscing aliquet bibendum. Etiam sed pretium tellus. Curabitur euismod dolor id suscipit vehicula. Sed tincidunt arcu sed velit convallis, id volutpat metus scelerisque. Phasellus tempus et elit eu dictum. Suspendisse tempus justo neque, id semper dui molestie nec. Aliquam luctus dui ac commodo laoreet.</p>

<p>Donec non ligula et urna dapibus euismod et nec tortor. Nullam mauris dui, dignissim vel varius et, eleifend at felis. Curabitur adipiscing nisi sed elit interdum ultricies. In sit amet turpis quis nisl porttitor facilisis vel quis justo. Curabitur fringilla viverra sodales. Nulla eget molestie quam. Etiam sed mi tellus. Ut fermentum diam sem, vel dictum mauris elementum aliquet. Vestibulum sed nibh felis. Nullam ac consectetur lectus, feugiat congue velit. Phasellus ullamcorper, erat eget volutpat semper, erat risus rutrum urna, sit amet lacinia augue tortor sit amet libero. Nam rutrum pulvinar nisl elementum aliquet. Duis ac blandit arcu.</p>

<p>Aenean nec massa est. Vivamus lobortis rutrum augue, eget luctus felis mattis non. Nulla lacinia, turpis non aliquet pretium, leo neque vulputate turpis, sit amet lobortis magna leo quis libero. Praesent id leo consequat, blandit ipsum in, scelerisque libero. Integer sagittis tempus neque, vel faucibus risus porttitor eu. Morbi euismod, enim non aliquam blandit, ligula tellus pellentesque dui, a posuere neque tellus non mi. Donec commodo sit amet lorem nec tristique. Donec eget neque massa. Morbi adipiscing mauris nec orci pharetra, tincidunt placerat nulla cursus. Quisque pulvinar lacinia nunc nec faucibus. Aliquam lorem arcu, scelerisque a turpis nec, tincidunt feugiat lacus. Nam elementum vitae diam luctus elementum. Mauris a ligula vel tortor lacinia posuere. Sed vestibulum at nisl eget mattis. Maecenas eget dignissim mauris, id aliquet quam. Nullam viverra lorem eu mollis rutrum.</p>

<a name="freight"></a><h2 class="text-info" style="margin-top:20px;">Freight Audit</h2>

<p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mattis purus nec lorem dignissim consectetur. Phasellus nibh massa, molestie et malesuada ac, eleifend eu nunc. Curabitur eget enim quis lorem venenatis semper. Aliquam nec laoreet arcu, luctus egestas velit. Nunc convallis nisl id velit euismod, ut iaculis est facilisis. Fusce luctus neque justo, ut consequat justo porta non. Duis mollis malesuada eros in lacinia. Integer ac tristique nisi. Donec bibendum rutrum odio.</p>

<p>Quisque mattis dui metus, in congue ante dictum ut. Sed posuere laoreet pulvinar. Nunc bibendum sapien eget leo luctus, ut bibendum velit sodales. Nam in bibendum erat. Sed a mattis quam, eget dignissim urna. Aliquam tristique purus adipiscing aliquet bibendum. Etiam sed pretium tellus. Curabitur euismod dolor id suscipit vehicula. Sed tincidunt arcu sed velit convallis, id volutpat metus scelerisque. Phasellus tempus et elit eu dictum. Suspendisse tempus justo neque, id semper dui molestie nec. Aliquam luctus dui ac commodo laoreet.</p>

<p>Donec non ligula et urna dapibus euismod et nec tortor. Nullam mauris dui, dignissim vel varius et, eleifend at felis. Curabitur adipiscing nisi sed elit interdum ultricies. In sit amet turpis quis nisl porttitor facilisis vel quis justo. Curabitur fringilla viverra sodales. Nulla eget molestie quam. Etiam sed mi tellus. Ut fermentum diam sem, vel dictum mauris elementum aliquet. Vestibulum sed nibh felis. Nullam ac consectetur lectus, feugiat congue velit. Phasellus ullamcorper, erat eget volutpat semper, erat risus rutrum urna, sit amet lacinia augue tortor sit amet libero. Nam rutrum pulvinar nisl elementum aliquet. Duis ac blandit arcu.</p>

<p>Aenean nec massa est. Vivamus lobortis rutrum augue, eget luctus felis mattis non. Nulla lacinia, turpis non aliquet pretium, leo neque vulputate turpis, sit amet lobortis magna leo quis libero. Praesent id leo consequat, blandit ipsum in, scelerisque libero. Integer sagittis tempus neque, vel faucibus risus porttitor eu. Morbi euismod, enim non aliquam blandit, ligula tellus pellentesque dui, a posuere neque tellus non mi. Donec commodo sit amet lorem nec tristique. Donec eget neque massa. Morbi adipiscing mauris nec orci pharetra, tincidunt placerat nulla cursus. Quisque pulvinar lacinia nunc nec faucibus. Aliquam lorem arcu, scelerisque a turpis nec, tincidunt feugiat lacus. Nam elementum vitae diam luctus elementum. Mauris a ligula vel tortor lacinia posuere. Sed vestibulum at nisl eget mattis. Maecenas eget dignissim mauris, id aliquet quam. Nullam viverra lorem eu mollis rutrum.</p>

<a name="scope"></a><h2 class="text-info" style="margin-top:20px;">Project Scope</h2>

<p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mattis purus nec lorem dignissim consectetur. Phasellus nibh massa, molestie et malesuada ac, eleifend eu nunc. Curabitur eget enim quis lorem venenatis semper. Aliquam nec laoreet arcu, luctus egestas velit. Nunc convallis nisl id velit euismod, ut iaculis est facilisis. Fusce luctus neque justo, ut consequat justo porta non. Duis mollis malesuada eros in lacinia. Integer ac tristique nisi. Donec bibendum rutrum odio.</p>

<p>Quisque mattis dui metus, in congue ante dictum ut. Sed posuere laoreet pulvinar. Nunc bibendum sapien eget leo luctus, ut bibendum velit sodales. Nam in bibendum erat. Sed a mattis quam, eget dignissim urna. Aliquam tristique purus adipiscing aliquet bibendum. Etiam sed pretium tellus. Curabitur euismod dolor id suscipit vehicula. Sed tincidunt arcu sed velit convallis, id volutpat metus scelerisque. Phasellus tempus et elit eu dictum. Suspendisse tempus justo neque, id semper dui molestie nec. Aliquam luctus dui ac commodo laoreet.</p>

<p>Donec non ligula et urna dapibus euismod et nec tortor. Nullam mauris dui, dignissim vel varius et, eleifend at felis. Curabitur adipiscing nisi sed elit interdum ultricies. In sit amet turpis quis nisl porttitor facilisis vel quis justo. Curabitur fringilla viverra sodales. Nulla eget molestie quam. Etiam sed mi tellus. Ut fermentum diam sem, vel dictum mauris elementum aliquet. Vestibulum sed nibh felis. Nullam ac consectetur lectus, feugiat congue velit. Phasellus ullamcorper, erat eget volutpat semper, erat risus rutrum urna, sit amet lacinia augue tortor sit amet libero. Nam rutrum pulvinar nisl elementum aliquet. Duis ac blandit arcu.</p>

<p>Aenean nec massa est. Vivamus lobortis rutrum augue, eget luctus felis mattis non. Nulla lacinia, turpis non aliquet pretium, leo neque vulputate turpis, sit amet lobortis magna leo quis libero. Praesent id leo consequat, blandit ipsum in, scelerisque libero. Integer sagittis tempus neque, vel faucibus risus porttitor eu. Morbi euismod, enim non aliquam blandit, ligula tellus pellentesque dui, a posuere neque tellus non mi. Donec commodo sit amet lorem nec tristique. Donec eget neque massa. Morbi adipiscing mauris nec orci pharetra, tincidunt placerat nulla cursus. Quisque pulvinar lacinia nunc nec faucibus. Aliquam lorem arcu, scelerisque a turpis nec, tincidunt feugiat lacus. Nam elementum vitae diam luctus elementum. Mauris a ligula vel tortor lacinia posuere. Sed vestibulum at nisl eget mattis. Maecenas eget dignissim mauris, id aliquet quam. Nullam viverra lorem eu mollis rutrum.</p>

<a name="non-parcelAudit"></a><h2 class="text-info" style="margin-top:20px;">Non-Parcel Audit</h2>

<p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mattis purus nec lorem dignissim consectetur. Phasellus nibh massa, molestie et malesuada ac, eleifend eu nunc. Curabitur eget enim quis lorem venenatis semper. Aliquam nec laoreet arcu, luctus egestas velit. Nunc convallis nisl id velit euismod, ut iaculis est facilisis. Fusce luctus neque justo, ut consequat justo porta non. Duis mollis malesuada eros in lacinia. Integer ac tristique nisi. Donec bibendum rutrum odio.</p>

<p>Quisque mattis dui metus, in congue ante dictum ut. Sed posuere laoreet pulvinar. Nunc bibendum sapien eget leo luctus, ut bibendum velit sodales. Nam in bibendum erat. Sed a mattis quam, eget dignissim urna. Aliquam tristique purus adipiscing aliquet bibendum. Etiam sed pretium tellus. Curabitur euismod dolor id suscipit vehicula. Sed tincidunt arcu sed velit convallis, id volutpat metus scelerisque. Phasellus tempus et elit eu dictum. Suspendisse tempus justo neque, id semper dui molestie nec. Aliquam luctus dui ac commodo laoreet.</p>

<p>Donec non ligula et urna dapibus euismod et nec tortor. Nullam mauris dui, dignissim vel varius et, eleifend at felis. Curabitur adipiscing nisi sed elit interdum ultricies. In sit amet turpis quis nisl porttitor facilisis vel quis justo. Curabitur fringilla viverra sodales. Nulla eget molestie quam. Etiam sed mi tellus. Ut fermentum diam sem, vel dictum mauris elementum aliquet. Vestibulum sed nibh felis. Nullam ac consectetur lectus, feugiat congue velit. Phasellus ullamcorper, erat eget volutpat semper, erat risus rutrum urna, sit amet lacinia augue tortor sit amet libero. Nam rutrum pulvinar nisl elementum aliquet. Duis ac blandit arcu.</p>

<p>Aenean nec massa est. Vivamus lobortis rutrum augue, eget luctus felis mattis non. Nulla lacinia, turpis non aliquet pretium, leo neque vulputate turpis, sit amet lobortis magna leo quis libero. Praesent id leo consequat, blandit ipsum in, scelerisque libero. Integer sagittis tempus neque, vel faucibus risus porttitor eu. Morbi euismod, enim non aliquam blandit, ligula tellus pellentesque dui, a posuere neque tellus non mi. Donec commodo sit amet lorem nec tristique. Donec eget neque massa. Morbi adipiscing mauris nec orci pharetra, tincidunt placerat nulla cursus. Quisque pulvinar lacinia nunc nec faucibus. Aliquam lorem arcu, scelerisque a turpis nec, tincidunt feugiat lacus. Nam elementum vitae diam luctus elementum. Mauris a ligula vel tortor lacinia posuere. Sed vestibulum at nisl eget mattis. Maecenas eget dignissim mauris, id aliquet quam. Nullam viverra lorem eu mollis rutrum.</p>

<a name="parcelAudit"></a><h2 class="text-info" style="margin-top:20px;">Parcel Audit</h2>

<p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mattis purus nec lorem dignissim consectetur. Phasellus nibh massa, molestie et malesuada ac, eleifend eu nunc. Curabitur eget enim quis lorem venenatis semper. Aliquam nec laoreet arcu, luctus egestas velit. Nunc convallis nisl id velit euismod, ut iaculis est facilisis. Fusce luctus neque justo, ut consequat justo porta non. Duis mollis malesuada eros in lacinia. Integer ac tristique nisi. Donec bibendum rutrum odio.</p>

<p>Quisque mattis dui metus, in congue ante dictum ut. Sed posuere laoreet pulvinar. Nunc bibendum sapien eget leo luctus, ut bibendum velit sodales. Nam in bibendum erat. Sed a mattis quam, eget dignissim urna. Aliquam tristique purus adipiscing aliquet bibendum. Etiam sed pretium tellus. Curabitur euismod dolor id suscipit vehicula. Sed tincidunt arcu sed velit convallis, id volutpat metus scelerisque. Phasellus tempus et elit eu dictum. Suspendisse tempus justo neque, id semper dui molestie nec. Aliquam luctus dui ac commodo laoreet.</p>

<p>Donec non ligula et urna dapibus euismod et nec tortor. Nullam mauris dui, dignissim vel varius et, eleifend at felis. Curabitur adipiscing nisi sed elit interdum ultricies. In sit amet turpis quis nisl porttitor facilisis vel quis justo. Curabitur fringilla viverra sodales. Nulla eget molestie quam. Etiam sed mi tellus. Ut fermentum diam sem, vel dictum mauris elementum aliquet. Vestibulum sed nibh felis. Nullam ac consectetur lectus, feugiat congue velit. Phasellus ullamcorper, erat eget volutpat semper, erat risus rutrum urna, sit amet lacinia augue tortor sit amet libero. Nam rutrum pulvinar nisl elementum aliquet. Duis ac blandit arcu.</p>

<p>Aenean nec massa est. Vivamus lobortis rutrum augue, eget luctus felis mattis non. Nulla lacinia, turpis non aliquet pretium, leo neque vulputate turpis, sit amet lobortis magna leo quis libero. Praesent id leo consequat, blandit ipsum in, scelerisque libero. Integer sagittis tempus neque, vel faucibus risus porttitor eu. Morbi euismod, enim non aliquam blandit, ligula tellus pellentesque dui, a posuere neque tellus non mi. Donec commodo sit amet lorem nec tristique. Donec eget neque massa. Morbi adipiscing mauris nec orci pharetra, tincidunt placerat nulla cursus. Quisque pulvinar lacinia nunc nec faucibus. Aliquam lorem arcu, scelerisque a turpis nec, tincidunt feugiat lacus. Nam elementum vitae diam luctus elementum. Mauris a ligula vel tortor lacinia posuere. Sed vestibulum at nisl eget mattis. Maecenas eget dignissim mauris, id aliquet quam. Nullam viverra lorem eu mollis rutrum.</p>

<a name="duties"></a><h2 class="text-info" style="margin-top:20px;">Duties</h2>

<p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mattis purus nec lorem dignissim consectetur. Phasellus nibh massa, molestie et malesuada ac, eleifend eu nunc. Curabitur eget enim quis lorem venenatis semper. Aliquam nec laoreet arcu, luctus egestas velit. Nunc convallis nisl id velit euismod, ut iaculis est facilisis. Fusce luctus neque justo, ut consequat justo porta non. Duis mollis malesuada eros in lacinia. Integer ac tristique nisi. Donec bibendum rutrum odio.</p>

<p>Quisque mattis dui metus, in congue ante dictum ut. Sed posuere laoreet pulvinar. Nunc bibendum sapien eget leo luctus, ut bibendum velit sodales. Nam in bibendum erat. Sed a mattis quam, eget dignissim urna. Aliquam tristique purus adipiscing aliquet bibendum. Etiam sed pretium tellus. Curabitur euismod dolor id suscipit vehicula. Sed tincidunt arcu sed velit convallis, id volutpat metus scelerisque. Phasellus tempus et elit eu dictum. Suspendisse tempus justo neque, id semper dui molestie nec. Aliquam luctus dui ac commodo laoreet.</p>

<p>Donec non ligula et urna dapibus euismod et nec tortor. Nullam mauris dui, dignissim vel varius et, eleifend at felis. Curabitur adipiscing nisi sed elit interdum ultricies. In sit amet turpis quis nisl porttitor facilisis vel quis justo. Curabitur fringilla viverra sodales. Nulla eget molestie quam. Etiam sed mi tellus. Ut fermentum diam sem, vel dictum mauris elementum aliquet. Vestibulum sed nibh felis. Nullam ac consectetur lectus, feugiat congue velit. Phasellus ullamcorper, erat eget volutpat semper, erat risus rutrum urna, sit amet lacinia augue tortor sit amet libero. Nam rutrum pulvinar nisl elementum aliquet. Duis ac blandit arcu.</p>

<p>Aenean nec massa est. Vivamus lobortis rutrum augue, eget luctus felis mattis non. Nulla lacinia, turpis non aliquet pretium, leo neque vulputate turpis, sit amet lobortis magna leo quis libero. Praesent id leo consequat, blandit ipsum in, scelerisque libero. Integer sagittis tempus neque, vel faucibus risus porttitor eu. Morbi euismod, enim non aliquam blandit, ligula tellus pellentesque dui, a posuere neque tellus non mi. Donec commodo sit amet lorem nec tristique. Donec eget neque massa. Morbi adipiscing mauris nec orci pharetra, tincidunt placerat nulla cursus. Quisque pulvinar lacinia nunc nec faucibus. Aliquam lorem arcu, scelerisque a turpis nec, tincidunt feugiat lacus. Nam elementum vitae diam luctus elementum. Mauris a ligula vel tortor lacinia posuere. Sed vestibulum at nisl eget mattis. Maecenas eget dignissim mauris, id aliquet quam. Nullam viverra lorem eu mollis rutrum.</p>

<a name="comments"></a><h2 class="text-info" style="margin-top:20px;">Comments</h2>

<textarea name="notes" cols="10" class="fullWidthField" id="notes" style="border:0px none; height:200px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sit amet justo mauris. Cras non rhoncus nibh. Duis odio enim, euismod a magna a, semper euismod nulla. Pellentesque nec dui justo. Sed in pulvinar risus. Maecenas et metus eu metus varius feugiat quis eu felis. Maecenas leo felis, dapibus ac tellus et, dapibus congue nisl. Etiam auctor sapien metus, et varius urna vestibulum vel. Etiam laoreet turpis ut lectus interdum, quis pretium sem suscipit. Suspendisse felis nulla, tincidunt nec aliquet eu, elementum ac urna. Curabitur sollicitudin euismod diam in iaculis.</textarea>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

</div>

  <div class="col-md-3" id="myScrollspy">

    <ul class="nav affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="50">


      <li><a href="#steps">Implementation Steps</a></li>

      <li><a href="#routing">Pre Audit, Routing &amp; Access Info</a></li>

      <li><a href="#contract">Contract Details</a></li>

      <li><a href="#freight">Freight Audit</a></li>

      <li><a href="#scope">Project Scope</a></li>

      <li><a href="#non-parcelAudit">Non-Parcel Audit</a></li>

      <li><a href="#parcelAudit">Parcel Audit</a></li>

      <li><a href="#duties">Duties</a></li>

      <li><a href="#comments">Comments</a></li>

    </ul>

  </div>

</div> <!-- container -->

<!-- -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= -->

<!-- -=-=-=-=-=-=-= MODAL WINDOW CODE-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= -->

<!-- -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= -->

<div id="mWindow" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header" id="mHeader">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

        <h2 class="text-info" id="myModalLabel"></h2>

      </div>



      <div class="modal-body" id="mBody"></div>

      <div class="modal-footer" id="mFooter"></div>

  </div>

 </div>

</div>



<div id="timeout" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

        <h2 id="myModalLabel" class="text-info">Anybody There?</h2>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

        <p>It appears that you have been inactive for quite some time. Unless you press the button below, your session will be cancelled and you will be logged out.</p>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" />I'm Still Here

      </div>

  </div>

 </div>

</div> 

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using

```
<a name="routing"></a>
```

but instead should be using an id, like:

```
<h2 id="routing" class="text-info" style="margin-top:20px;">
```

As the docs say:

> Resolvable ID targets required
>   Navbar links must have resolvable id targets. For example, a <a href="#home">home</a> must correspond to something in the DOM like <div id="home"></div>.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: Thanks for responding. Sadly, i suck at understanding those docs. I tried doing exactly what you said and nothing... here's what my h2 looks like: <h2 id="comments" class="text-info" style="margin-top:20px;">Comments</h2> and my ul looks like this:<ul class="nav affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="50" id="myScrollspy"><li><a href="#comments">Comments</a></li></ul> .... Still nothing. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Here's a link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grem28/JgGTe/  Open up the result window tall & wide. Another weird thing i noticed here is that even though i have an "active" class on the main information (li), it doesn't show... maybe related? Thanks